# SQL Get the gaps in dateranges when a list of ranges is provided

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm currently looking for a SQL solution for the following problem:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ced3c/1) as guidance:

I have a list of not-nullable startdates and nullable enddates. Based on this list I need the total gap time between a given start and enddate.

Based on the SQLFiddle

If I would only have situation 1 in my database the result should be 2 days.
If I would have situation 2 and 3 in my database the result should be 1 day.

I have been pondering this for a couple of days now... any help would be much appreciated!

Regards,
Kyor

Notes: I'm running SQL 2012 ( should any special new features be required )

Comment: Do you need the number of overlapping days for each row in `dateranges`?

Comment: No I only need the gaps, not the overlaps. So the days between the given range where no date is find in the given list of ranges.

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all possible dates?

Comment: No I mean like Dates table with a record for each day

Comment: No, that would have to be generated on the fly I guess.

Comment: Also situation 1 has a full overlap with your given range, so I am not sure where a gap of 1 day comes from.

Comment: Can you show us exact sample data or based on the fiddle, what is your exact desired/expected output results?

Comment: Updates post with proper example => see SQLFiddle

Comment: Can you post the expected output based on your SQLFiddle?

Comment: See the question: if only situation 1 would be in the database, the result should be that there is 2 days short to fill up the given range . If situation 2 and 3 where the only values in the database, the result should be that there is 1 day missing the given daterange.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution will be to create 'Dates' table and start from there, otherwise solution will be unmaintainable. For each date in specified range you can check whether it is covered by ranges in 'dateranges' table and get a count of dates that are not.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  Dates d
WHERE
  d.Date BETWEEN @start AND @end
AND NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * 
  FROM dateranges r
  WHERE d.date BETWEEN r.startdate and ISNULL(r.enddate, d.date) 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE Dates (
 dt DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO Dates VALUES('20081204'); 
INSERT INTO Dates VALUES('20081205');
INSERT INTO Dates VALUES('20090608');
INSERT INTO Dates VALUES('20090609');

-- missing ranges
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, prev) AS start_gap,
       DATEADD(DAY, -1, next) AS end_gap,
       DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, prev), 
                       DATEADD(DAY, -1, next)) AS month_diff
FROM (
SELECT dt AS prev, 
      (SELECT MIN(dt) 
       FROM Dates AS B
       WHERE B.dt > A.dt) AS next
FROM Dates AS A) AS T
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, prev, next) > 1;

-- existing ranges
SELECT MIN(dt) AS start_range,
       MAX(dt) AS end_range
FROM (
SELECT dt, 
       DATEDIFF(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt), dt) AS grp
FROM Dates) AS D
GROUP BY grp;

DROP TABLE Dates;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I'm looking for. This covers sequential records of dates, not date ranges.

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/find-missing-date-ranges-in-sql/
Is that article something that would help you ?